# Why sess.run(tf.assign) take longer time to execute after each epoch?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I wrote a function to update trainable variables after each epoch by tf.assign() function with new value is numpy array and shape of trainable variables do not change after each epoch. But when epoch increase, time to run this code increase too although number and shape of trainable variables is the same. Is there anyone can explain about this phenomenon?

```py
start_time = time.time()
for i, v in enumerate(tf.trainable_variables()):
    v_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name(v.name)
    sess.run(tf.assign(v_tensor, value[i]))
print('Time to update trainable variables: {}'.format(time.time() - start_time))
```

As you can see, the time to run this code increases after each epoch:

```
Time to update trainable variables: 0.20442891120910645
Time to update trainable variables: 0.31240272521972656
Time to update trainable variables: 0.44904398918151855
Time to update trainable variables: 0.6219220161437988
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run that code multiple times, then you will be creating more and more replicated ops in the graph, which will slow things down. Instead, create the assignment ops only once:

```
assignment_ops = []
for i, v in enumerate(tf.trainable_variables()):
    v_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name(v.name)
    assignment_ops.append(tf.assign(v_tensor, value[i]))
```

Then, whenever you need to actually perform the assignment, just run the previously created ops:

```
sess.run(assignment_ops)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although the time decreased, it still increase when the epoch increase (0.0194 -> 0.0279 -> 0.0365 -> 0.0457 ...). I have used tf.reset_default_graph() when the epoch increase to reduce the replicated ops but it's not work. What should i do?

Comment: @thangbk2209 It is possible that you are still adding new ops to the graph in each iteration. It is important that you make sure that all the ops are created in advance and not constantly recreated. On thing you can do (at least for debugging, maybe you want to remove it later) is add a call to [`finalize()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#finalize) on the graph once you think you have all your ops added. If you get an error after that it's because you are trying to add still more ops.